# Is every React Library also requirable in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, mern

Let's say there is a library that I can import in react simply by doing:

```
import {Something} from someLibrary
```

Is it always the case that I can also use that library on my backend written in nodejs like as follows:

```
const someLibrary = require(someLibrary)
```

If it is not always the case, how do I know when I can and when I can't?

**So to sum it up**
Can all react libraries be imported/required in nodejs? If not, what is a neat way to know when it can be done and when it can't.

This is something I have had in the back of my mind for quite sometime now.

Comment: While I can not simply answer your question, I suggest you read https://blog.logrocket.com/commonjs-vs-es-modules-node-js/ to understand the differences.

Comment: You can use `import {Something} from someLibrary` in nodejs as well

Answer (score 2):

Require statement is required when node js version is **<= v13** (less then 13) and using ES-5

Import statement is required when node js version is **>= v13** (more then 13) and using ES-6 (import introduce in ES6)

How to use ES6 in import in Node.js

It's very simple in **Node.js 13 and above**. You need to either:

- Save the file with .mjs extension, or
- Add **{ "type": "module" }** in the nearest **package.json**.